# map with custom comparator not work

Tags: c++

I have wrote a map with an own comparator, and test the find function. But it seems not work. The code is showing below, I want to create a map whose key type is a pair and value type is an int. when I run the code, it always output "not find" rather than some values store in the map. Could anybody tell me why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct Mycomp {
    bool operator() (const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b) {
        int firsta = a.first;
        int seconda = a.second;
        if(firsta > seconda) {
            int temp = firsta;
            firsta = seconda;
            seconda = temp;
        }
        int firstb = b.first;
        int secondb = b.second;
        if(firstb > secondb) {
            int temp = firstb;
            firstb = secondb;
            secondb = temp;
        }
        if(firsta != firstb) 
            return firsta <= firstb;
        else
            return seconda <= secondb;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    map<pair<int, int>, int, Mycomp> mymap;
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(0, 1), 10));
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(2, 3), 10));
    auto it = mymap.find(std::make_pair(1, 0));
    if(it == mymap.end())
        out << "not find" << endl;
    else
        cout << it->second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your comparator is not a strict weak ordering. Basically, a comparator should model `<`, not `<=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the comment by @IgorTandetnik to an answer.

Replace the lines:

```
if(firsta != firstb) 
    return firsta <= firstb;
else
    return seconda <= secondb;
```

by

```
if(firsta != firstb) 
    return firsta < firstb;  // Use < not <=
else
    return seconda < secondb;
```